# OpenCV Good features to track performance on some builds

Tags: qt, opencv

I am encountering this really frustrating problem, and I have no idea what the cause of it is. Sometimes when I build and run the project, the OpenCV goodFeaturesToTrack function will take 10 times longer to process than normal, bringing my entire application to a screeching halt.

This only happens occassionally, then when I fidget with the project, doing nothing more than adding things like print statements, the problem goes away and the function takes the normal time to run.

I thought what might be happening is that I may be linking in the debug libs somehow, but I have literally deleted the debug libs and the problem keeps happening.

I am also using QT Creator to build.

Any thoughts on how to diagnose this problem would be extremely helpful. Everytime it comes back I can lose up to a full day trying random things to make it go away!

Comment: Without any code, it is hard to make a guess...

Comment: please add some of your code so we can see if there is something wrong

Comment: My code has nothing to do with it, other opencv functions in completely different areas of the code also experience performance problems. The EXACT same inputs are going into the cv::goodFeaturesToTrack function when it is slow versus when it is fast.